# The behavior of std::advance at the end of std::list

Tags: c++, list, c++11, stl, iterator

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  list<int> A;
  A.push_back(1);
  A.push_back(2);
  A.push_back(3);

  auto it = A.begin();
  cout << *it << ' ';
  advance(it, 1);
  cout << *it << ' ';
  advance(it, 1);
  cout << *it << ' ';
  advance(it, 1);
  cout << *it << ' ';
  advance(it, 1);
  cout << *it << ' ';
}
```

I belive that `list` is a double linked list.
Surprisingly, the output is `1 2 3 3 1`.
Can someone explain what's happening here?
Here are questions:

1. When we advance twice, we are at the node with `3`.
   Here, an additional `advance` moves the iterator to `A.end()`.
   I believe that `A.end()` is an imaginary node that does not point to the original element. However, it prints out `3`. Why?
2. How come it prints out `1` at the end? The `list` is not a circular queue.

Comment: Welcome to undefined behavior land where whatever happens is correct.

Comment: you seem to be jumping to the conclusion that the `1` you see is the `1` from the front of the list, but its just a `1`. Even if the next numbers were `2` and `3` theres no way you could tell that is the numbers in the list. Anyhow, its undefined and output could be anything

Comment: I see, that means I have to do the range check before using `std::advance`. Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: Yes, never forget the range checking! The STL (which was the foundation of these containers and algorithms) was designed as a sharp tool for people that pay attention. There are no nets that will catch you, but you don't pay the performance penalty either. Most implementations nowadays come with a diagnostic mode though which can safe you from that for development purposes. You need to activate it explicitly though. How to do that should be documented.

Comment: or you know that there are enough element without checking. I mean in this current example you also know that you are going beyond the end of the list, no check really needed

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt MSVC is good at this, a lot of checks are enabled automatically in debug builds.

Comment: In addition to checking the iterator before advancing it, it is necessary to check it before dereferencing it.  If `it` is an end iterator, then evaluating `*it`  and/or calling `advance(it, ...)` each give undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dereferencing the end iterator is undefined. The end iterator points one past the last element in the list. It does not not refer to an element in the list, because there is no element past the last.

Advancing the end iterator further is undefined as well.

Your program has undefined behavior.

Undefined behavior means anything can happen. The runtime behavior of code without undefined behavior is specified in the langauge standard (some is implementation defined or unspecified, but lets keep it simple). On the other hand, when your code has undefined behavior then you get no guarantee what the resulting program runtime behavior will be. Your output could be `"Hello World"`.

Of course the output is not `"Hello World"` and there is a reason why you see the output you do see. Though, these reasons are not related to how C++ works. To understand why you get the output you get you would have to study the assembly generated by the compiler. Eventually to understand why the compiler did generate this assembly you would need to study implementation details of your compiler. However, if you want to learn about C++ then any of this is futile and all you need to know is that your code has undefined behavior.

Comment: .....  and (except in specialised use cases, such as deliberate usage of compiler-specific extensions) that it is best to write code (do whatever checks are necessary) to *avoid* undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the program and it crashed